# Error when using Merge() in NHibernate: a different object with the same identifier

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, session-per-request

I'm using  FluentNHibernate and when i make post got this error.

> a different object with the same identifier value was already
>   associated with the session

That is my Controller:

```
private readonly ITicketAppService _ticketAppService;
public TicketController()
    {
        ITicketAppService ticketAppService = new TicketAppService(new TicketService(new TicketRepository(), new RomaneioCodRepository(), new ParamGerarMZRepository()));

    }

public ResponseApi Post(Ticket ticket)
     {
        var result = new ResponseApi();
        try{
        //my code goes here
        //my code goes here
        //my code goes here


        _ticketAppService.Add(ticket);
       _ticketAppService.Commit();

       result.DocsSaved.AddRange(ticket.ROMANEIOs);

       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
         _ticketAppService.RollBack();
         result.Errors.Add(new Erro(ex));
       }
       return result;
     }
```

And that is my Add on RepositoryBase:

```
public virtual void Add(TEntity obj)
        {
            try
            {
                BeginTrasaction();
                Db.Merge(obj);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.ErrorFormat("Erro ao tentar adicionar alterações. Detalhes: {0}", ex);
                throw new Exception("Erro ao tentar adicionar registro.", ex);
            }
        }
```

All questions as i see sayed for use Merge() cause NHibernate try save one ID from user as is already on session, but i got the same error using Merge().
And i'm also using session-per-request.
And i have tried make the same on this [documentation](http://pro-programmers.blogspot.com.br/2009/03/hibernate-nonuniqueobjectexception.html).
Someone know's how can i fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the same entity from multiple places using the same session,  `Merge` method is used for attach an entity from different session.

Read this Ayende's [article](http://ayende.com/blog/4282/nhibernate-cross-session-operations).

Comment: Where i'm getting from multiple places? Cause i'm gotting direct from my paramether in post. I think i have understood this article, but i have also tried make save, saveorupdate, and i asked with Merge() cause every where said for use Merge and this will resolve.

Comment: That is could be the problem, check if your app load more than once the same instace monitoring the queries generated by nhibernate?